# Android Drag onto screen layout

Tags: android, layout, drag, effect

How would you recreate the drag onto screen layout/effect similar to the one on some android home screen devices?

Specifically there is a bar at the top of the home screen and that you can put your finger on and drag down.  When you drag it another screen comes down from the top of the screen. On my phone this screen has shortcust to wifi, bluetooth, gps, etc..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a slidingdrawer control.  Here is a tutorial: http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-viewflipper-and-slidingdrawer.html