# Switching between activities (notification panel - style)

Tags: android, user-interface

I have 2 activities in my android app -  mainActivity and mapActivity.
And I would like to use custom animation to switch between them.
The problem is - i would like my mapActivity to apper over the main activity just the same way (with the same behaviour) the Notification panel appears on all Androids - using vertical sliding, but from bottom to top. Is there any way to accomplish this?

thank you very much

tania

UPD: just to make it clear - i need not only SLIDING, but also this "dragging-releasing" behaviour the regular notification panel has

(so my question is NOT a duplicate)

UPD2: i know about overridePendingTransition -  but how to work out the  "dragging-releasing" behaviour ??

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055984/display-page-from-bottom-to-top

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259736/android-drag-onto-screen-layout?rq=1


here is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to drag it up and down I think your only option (or easiest option at least) is to merge the two activities into one. and create the map portion as a [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) Or use some sort of customized View / Fragment to make it dragable.

I think it will be very difficult to make that work on top of Androids idea of an Activity

Comment: thank you very much. ill try to follow your advise, and will share my expirience after that

Answer (score 1):

Personally I didn't have any prior experience with things like this, but this thread seems to have a receipe for this question: [Activity transition in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)